# How to use <TabControl.ContentTemplate> to traverse the display content in the xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using materialDesign open source UI library to develop, for  I want to use data template to display, the code is as follows, but the display style of the interface is not correct, the display logic is also not correct

```
<materialDesign:Card>
<TabControl VerticalContentAlignment="Top" materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="PrimaryMid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding IndexMenus}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignNavigationRailTabControl}">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=TabControl}}" />
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TabItem Margin="0,25,0,0">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Width="auto" Height="auto">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Kind="{Binding Icon}" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

</materialDesign:Card>

This is what it looks like now
[image]

If the data template is not used, he will show this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ItemTemplate` instead of `ContentTemplate`

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TabItem Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Width="auto" Height="auto">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Kind="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```